# unable to upload images with pillow

Tags: django, python-imaging-library

I tried uploading images from the django admin but the images uploads as an empty image. Here's my settings for my project

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')`
```

And here's my html for my html handler:

```
<div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-3 ">
      <img class="featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" src="{crimes.images}" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="200" height="200">
```

Comment: You should use two curly braces, so `{{crimes.images}}` although the name seems to suggest this is *not* a single image...

Comment: thanks @willem,sorry in my models it's just image here's my model for more clarity   image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)

Comment: did u add `MEDIA_URL` to your `urls.py` file?

Comment: @chiefir,i didnt can you please an example for me..thanks

Comment: @Kelechi Nweke check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Do u have something like this in your `urls.py` file? As it is said [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development).

```
if DEBUG:

    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    urlpatterns += static(
        MEDIA_URL,
        document_root=MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: ,i did exactly what you recommended but yet it won't stil upload

Comment: Show your model

Comment: @Chiefr, I've resolved the problem.. thanks a million